# Pixelated UIImage after changing color

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Using extension in Swift. Changing the overlay color of a `UIImage` results in grainy/pixelated image.

```
extension UIImage{
    func tint(color: UIColor) -> UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        // The below 2 lines, Scaling & Translating doesn't have any affect.
        // I read in some post to add this as fix but it doesn't work

        context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context!.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -self.size.height)

        context!.setBlendMode(.multiply)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        context!.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)

        color.setFill()
        context!.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there another/better approach?

*Solutions in Objective-C are also welcomed.*

Comment: @Keiwan Great! It worked. Many thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1623912-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwitho).

This function lets you pass in the scale factor to apply to the image as the third parameter. If you specify `0.0` for this value, it'll be automatically set to the main screen's scale (which is useful for retina displays).

In your case the call would be

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, 0.0)
```

*The second argument specifies whether the image's alpha channel should be ignored or not.*